# Real time update for charts/data without setinterval?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I know its not a specific question but we have an criptocurrency exchange plataform and we would like to update data for users (ie. an table with current active sell orders) or a chart, actually we use setinterval, but I think its very heavy, and there's too many things to update every 1 second, there's an exchange (www.bittrex.com) that update those orders instantly and i really dont think they use setinterval. I know server-side cant send commands to user, but is there ANY way to tell user to update only when server have new data available?

Actually we use jquery, php and laravel.

I'm asking this generic question because i tried to search on many ways on google and didn't found any start way.

Comment: websockets, server sent events, etc...

Comment: [Sockets](https://socket.io/), [Laravel broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting). The question is not really suitable for Stack Overflow. But this should get you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you @DanielA.White and devk for the reply. I'll go this way.

Comment: Server side _can_ send notification to clients. They can be achieved by either using traditional socket.io as others has mentioned, or [Pusher](https://pusher.com/docs/javascript_quick_start#listen-for-events-on-your-channel) (laravel has it out of the box), or [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging/), or some others I didn't know of :) Important is, don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Socket.Io` for realtime update. visit http://socket.io for more information